# How to test for String = Enum.Value?

Tags: vb.net, enums

How do I do a simple compare of an enum value and a string that should match the enums name?

How do I parse the string into it's appropriate enum value.

For example,

```
Enum A
     B=0
     C=1
     D=2
End Enum
```

How do I check if String = A.C and how do I convert string into its corresponding A value without comparing it to a string representation?

Comment: by the way, if you always want to the enum start with value 0 (zero) you do not need to say it, just B C D is enough

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several different methods that are related:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(A), A.C) == "C"
A.C.ToString() == "C"
((A)Enum.Parse(typeof(A), "C")) == A.C
```

The first two convert the value of `A.C` to a string representation (`"C"`) and then compare it to a string.  The last one converts the string `"C"` to a type `A`, and then compares as an actual type `A`.

Enum to string: `enumValue.ToString()` or `Enum.GetName(typeof(A), A.C)`

String to enum: `(A)Enum.Parse(typeof(A), "C")`

Note that none of those will really work if the enumeration is marked with `FlagsAttribute`.

Answer (score 7):

The [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) method:

> Converts the string representation of
>   the name or numeric value of one or
>   more enumerated constants to an
>   equivalent enumerated object. A
>   parameter specifies whether the
>   operation is case-sensitive.

Here's the VB.NET example code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx):

```
Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim colorStrings() As String = {"0", "2", "8", "blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red, Green"}
      For Each colorString As String In colorStrings
         Try
            Dim colorValue As Colors = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Colors), colorString, True), Colors)        
            If [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(Colors), colorValue) Or colorValue.ToString().Contains(",") Then 
               Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", colorString, colorValue.ToString())
            Else
               Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.", colorString)            
            End If                    
         Catch e As ArgumentException
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a member of the Colors enumeration.", colorString)
         End Try
      Next
   End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 5):

`Enum.GetName(typeof(A),enumValue)==stringValue`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the name() function to check this

```
A.C.name() == "C"
```